# Windows 10 can't access network drive after startup

Tags: windows-10, network-shares, nas

I have a Western Digital MyCloud NAS drive which refuses to be accessible after Windows 10 starts. It was mapped in Windows with the *\\server\resource* syntax and set to reconnect at sign-in. In Explorer, the drive is shown with a red cross, and programs trying to access it report errors.

[image: drive screenshot]

Surprisingly, if *I simply double-click the icon* I can use the NAS as normal. The red cross is then gone in Explorer.

**Update:** I've replaced my WD NAS with a Synology NAS. The problem persists, so it seems to be related to Windows or my client's hardware.

What can I try to get rid of this nuisance?

---

Some more info that may be relevant:

- The computer uses an Ethernet cable, but I have noticed at times that after waking up from hibernation it takes a couple of seconds before the network is there. Perhaps the network connection isn't established when Windows attempts to mount the drive?
- Logging out and in again, the drive still works.
- The NAS is used by Linux computers too (with Samba), and they don't have this problem.

Comment: I have the exact same problem, but for me, it all started when my modem/router got replaced to a bad one. I am working hard to get it replaced again, but it may be contributing to your situation too. Basically what this means is that windows logs you in before any network connectivity is up and running and thus it shows these as disconnected networks. There is a policy that states: "wait for network before logging in" but I find that it sometimes causes windows to wait for 30 seconds, then times out and continues the login with the same problem. Surprisingly occassionally, windows all is okay.

Comment: @LPChip: Yes, it's probably down to slow network connectivity combined with Windows not retrying to connect drives after an initial failed attempt. I guess this problem should be common for users with slow WiFi connections. I wonder if there's a registry hack or something else to change the way Windows does this? Maybe my router is slow, but it generally works well so I wouldn't want to replace it for this reason alone.

Comment: You may need to write a script to perform the reconnect when you sign in, but delay the task for a few seconds so the network has time to connect and settle. Makes sense. Source: https://winaero.com/blog/windows-10-reconnect-network-drives/

Comment: @Kinnectus: Looks spot on, I'll try it and report back later. Thanks.

Comment: This method has worked most of the time. In some rare cases, it fails.